# How is the octave debugger used?

Tags: debugging, octave

So I'm trying to use the octave debugger to detect where division by zero happens. For that it seems logical to use "debug_on_warning ()". However I'm just not understanding how to use this function call.
I mean should I place it in the script somewhere? but then how would the debugger start?
an example would be great!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Take a look at the [Debugging section](http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Debugging.html) of the Octave manual.

For your case, you should place `debug_on_warning (1)` at the top of your script so it stops when the warning happens and drops you in debug mode. Then type `dbwhere` to find out where you are.

An alternative, that's the way I do it, leave the command `keyboard` in certain areas where you think the problem may be. Then use `dbstep` to evaluate your script line by line.

Comment: A key point which I think is omitted from the manual is these functions seem to be ignored when running functions within an `octave --eval` on the command line. What I had to do was run `octave`, then `debug_on_error(1)`, then the command I was `eval`ing from some other script, to get the actual interactive debugger. I _guess_ this makes sense, in a way that only makes sense after you realize that's how it _is_. Not what I expected, though.

Answer (score 5):

**Solution for setting a breakpoint in octave**

Set breakpoint in file myOctaveCode.m in line 18

```
dbstop myOctaveCode 18
```

Call function

```
myOctaveCode
```

Debugger stops

```
stopped in /.../myOctaveCode.m at line 18
...
```

Now I can use the debugger

```
debug> who

Variables in the current scope:
...
```

When calling dbstep I will jump to the next line

```
debug> dbstep
```

Documentation: https://octave.org/doc/v4.4.1/Debug-Mode.html#Debug-Mode

***Remark***

My answer just fits to the question's title. It's not an exact answer for the question. But I hope it might help others who stumble upon that question while searching for general octave debugging hints. So please do not vote me down.

Comment: Definitely useful in starting the debugger at the top level m_file line 1, though I have yet to fully fathom the GUI buttons. I was surprised that there isn't a debugger button to start and hold at line 1 so that breakpoints could be added.

Comment: Would have been nice to have a shortcut for "dbstep" command